# onTriggerEnter and onTriggerExit in AR Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on augmented reality game and can use character controller and Main Camera's player tag for colliders response.

Is that how we can do the same thing by using AR Camera? Can we use different tag for AR camera?

Here's the link, hopefully through this you get my point.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTIjpo6cb6M

I have done this thing in Unity, but now I have problem, so how can I do this in augmented reality?

Comment: Why you don't check collision on GameObject? They can manage animations etc.

Comment: in my case  both models have box colliders set as triggers. When those collide (OnTriggerEnter) characters start to fight. OnTriggerExit fighting is stopped i have done this work in unity when first person controller comes closer two these animated models they start animation and when i move away they stop animation. Then i do the same thing in Vuforia but its not gona work. please tell me how i can do that in Vuforia.

Comment: var chestSound : AudioClip; 
var treasureChest : GameObject; 
 
function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {
 
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") { 

 
treasureChest.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play();
 
}
}
function OnTriggerExit (col : Collider) {
 if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
     treasureChest.GetComponent.<Animation>().Stop();
 }

Comment: I think colliders need more size than target.

Comment: i have this scrip for both models

Comment: if you don't mind i want private chat because i want to show you some screen shots of my game may be through these screen shots you understand whats going on.